# Jspreadsheet different cell type for one cell

Tags: javascript

I want to add a dropdown type cell. Like I want to make the B5 cell to be dropdown. How can I do this ?

[image]

I used the [jspreadsheet](https://bossanova.uk/jspreadsheet/v4/) plugin for this. Jspreadsheet is a JavaScript plugin that enables you to create rich online spreadsheets with features similar to Microsoft Excel and Google Sheets.

Here is my code.

```
<html>
<script src="https://bossanova.uk/jspreadsheet/v4/jexcel.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bossanova.uk/jspreadsheet/v4/jexcel.css" type="text/css" />
 
<script src="https://jsuites.net/v4/jsuites.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://jsuites.net/v4/jsuites.css" type="text/css" />
 
<div id="spreadsheet"></div>
 
<script>
var initialInvestData = [
    ['Text', '', 'USD'],
    ['Text', '', 'USD'],
    ['Text', '', 'USD'],
    ['Text', '', 'Years'],
    ['Dropdown', '', ''],
    ['Number', '', '%'],
    ['Text', '', 'USD'],
];
var initialInvestTable = jspreadsheet(document.getElementById('spreadsheet'), {
    data: initialInvestData,
    columns: [
        {
            width:300
        },
        {
            width:90
        },
        {
            width:90,
            // readOnly:true
        }
    ],
    cells: {
        B5: { type:'dropdown' }
    },
});
initialInvestTable.setMerge('B5', 2);
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the dropdown values like ```source: ['data', 'hello']```